# JavaScript - How to get the text of the first child of a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to build an array of fruits in JavaScript and to do so, I need to get text values of all `li` children of my `ul` element. I've made some good progress, in that I was able to find the number of children my list had.

```
$("#fruits-list > li").length
=> 6
```

I can also find elements by index. Here, I found the first element using this

```
$("#fruits-list > li")[0]
=> <li id="apple">Apple</li>
```

I'm able to get the element, but I'm unable to get the test value of it. Here, I'm trying to just get the text value `apple`, and I have tried just about everything. I've tried

1. `$("#fruits-list > li")[0].text`
2. `$("#fruits-list > li")[0].html`
3. `$("#fruits-list > li")[0].val`

I got `undefined` for all three of them. I also tried adding `()` at the end of all of them, but got `TypeError: Is not a function`.

I could not find an answer here on SO. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Strangely enough there's something called [**first**](https://api.jquery.com/first/)

Comment: Hmm, this is easily google-able, you know. `$("#fruits-list > li:first-child").text()`

Comment: first wouldn't work in this case. As I need to create an array. I plan on creating a loop, so I need  to know how to access a particular element

Comment: @user4703663 I don't get why you need to access the value with the index..? Can't you not just use `this` inside a `$("#fruits-list > li').each()`?

Comment: then `$("#fruits-list > li").each()` - this will loop all `li` elements

Comment: That might work as well. To be honest, I didn't think about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the bracket notation with an index on a jQuery element, you get a DOM element. Those objects can't be called with jQuery functions directly. Use [eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead.

Use

```
$("#fruits-list > li").eq(0).text()
```

Note that if your end goal is to build an array of the texts of the LI elements, you can simply do

```
var arr = $("#fruits-list > li").map(function(){ return $(this).text() }).get();
```

Answer (score 4):

`text`, `html` and `val` are not properties of the DOM, they are jQuery methods.

You could simply do a natural JS method.

```
document.querySelector("#fruits-list > li").textContent; //or innerText for legacy IE
```

`querySelector` returns the first item of a list of elements. (if you use jQuery, however, I suggest dystroy's answer)

Comment: Whoops! That's my bad

Answer (score 1):

When you access `$("#fruits-list > li")[0]`, you are getting an `HTMLElement` object, which is why you cannot use jQuery's function on it. dystroy's solution let's you use jQuery to get the text because `eq` returns an instance of jQuery. You can also do

```
$("#fruits-list > li")[0].textContent
```

Comment: Not on IE8, though: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Cool! Is that a new JQuery HTML/CSS method? I couldn't find it listed here. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_html.asp

Comment: @user4703663 I suggest using the jQuery documentation over the w3schools. The source is better than the media report ;)

Comment: Alright, I went over to http://api.jquery.com/ but I still couldn't find textContent. Does anyone have the source?

Comment: @user4703663 You won't find it in the jQuery documentation because the list item isn't wrapped in a jQuery object. You can find the documentation for the property here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent.